# Solving equation with for loops python

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix

I have arrays like this:

```
x = np.array([-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1])

weight = np.array([[0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5],
                   [-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5],
                   [0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]]) 
print(weight.shape)

bias=np.array([2, 2, 2])
print(bias)
weight = np.transpose(weight)
weight
```

You can run the above code which results to arrays bias and weight_ham and x:

```
bias = [2 2 2]

weight = array([[ 0.5, -0.5,  0.5],
                [-0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
                [ 0.5, -0.5,  0.5],
                [-0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
                [ 0.5, -0.5,  0.5],
                [-0.5,  0.5,  0.5]])
x = array([-1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1])
```

Now i want to calculate this equation:

[image]

the y_in array should be like this:

```
y_in = np.zeros((1, len(bias)))
```

What i don't understand is how can i compute that equation with for loop since i'm not really familiar with how should i write for loops.
if you didn't understand the equation you can see this example below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are required to use loops when you are already working with `numpy`, however the correct way would be:

```
>>> np.add(bias, np.dot(x[None, :], weight)).flatten()
array([1., 3., 0.])
```

But if you want loops:

```
y = []
for index_1, b in enumerate(bias):
    sum_ = b
    for index_2, val in enumerate(x):
        sum_ += x[index_2] * weight[index_2, index_1]
    y.append(sum_)

>>> y
[1.0, 3.0, 0.0]

# OR

>>> [b + sum(x_val * w for x_val, w in zip(x, weight[:,i])) for i, b in enumerate(bias)]
[1.0, 3.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting answer for your screenshot problem. You can use the same code for your original problem:

```
x = np.array([1,1,-1,-1])

weight = np.array([[0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5],
                   [-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,0.5],
                   ]) 

bias=np.array([2, 2])
weight = np.transpose(weight)
```

**One Liner:**

```
np.add(bias, np.dot(weight.T, x))
```

### **Using Loop:**

```
y_arr = []
for j in range(weight.shape[1]):
    y = (bias[j] + np.dot(weight[:,j].T, x))
    y_arr.append(y)
y_arr = np.array(y_arr)
```

---

**y_arr:**

```
array([3., 1.])
```

Comment: For your original case this will give you `[1. 3. 0.]`